# 'classList.contains'() isn't returning true on an CSS selector that contains specified class name

Tags: javascript, html

I tried both `classList.contains` and `!!el.querySelector() to figure out if the element contains the specified class. Below is my JS code followed by the HTML.

```js
const purchaseTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-option ul li');

// Declare variable for later use
//Note: selling plan ID differentiates subscription-only product from its regular version
var sellingPlan = 684884014;
var activeClassFound = false;
var activeTabIdentifier;
var gutArmorVariantID = 31638158934062;
var variantData = {
  'id': gutArmorVariantID,
  'quantity': 1,
};

// Find out active purchase tab on page load.
purchaseTabs.forEach((el) => {
  console.log("Inside purchaseTabs loop for active tab search");
  console.log("Current el: " + el.innerHTML);
  if (el.classList.contains("gf_tab-active")) {
    console.log("active tab found");
    activeClassFound = TRUE;
    activeTabIdentifier = el.getAttribute("data-index");
    // populate data JSON object and updateCart()
    // Note: 'selling_plan' is needed for subscription only product
    console.log("Active Tab: " + activeTabIdentifier);
    if (activeTabIdentifier == "2") {
      variantData.sellingplan = sellingPlan;
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

````html
<div class="gf_restabs module style1 gf_module-left purchase-option gf_restabs_accordion_0" data-activetab="1" data-tabbgcolor="#FFFFFF" data-tabcolor="#333333" data-inactivetabbgcolor="#e0e0e0" data-inactivetabcolor="#8d8d8d" data-bordercolor="#cecece"
  data-bordersize="2px" data-height="">
  <ul>
    <li class="gf_tab gf_tab-active" data-index="1" style="margin-left: 0px; border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><span class="item-content" data-index="1" data-key="content"><div data-label="Text Block" id="e-1688134412404-2" class="element-wrap" data-tool="0" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-id="1688134412404-2" data-ver="1"><div class="elm text-edit gf_gs-text-paragraph-1">One-time purchase</div></div></span>
      <span
        class="gf_tab-bottom" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 2px; bottom: -2px;"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="gf_tab" data-index="2" style="margin-left: -2px; border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206); background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgb(141, 141, 141);"><span class="item-content" data-index="2" data-key="content"><div data-label="Text Block" id="e-1688134412404-1" class="element-wrap" data-tool="0" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-id="1688134412404-1" data-ver="1"><div class="elm text-edit gf_gs-text-paragraph-1">Subscribe &amp; Save</div></div></span>
      <span
        class="gf_tab-bottom"></span>
    </li>
  </ul><span class="gf_tab-accordion-title"><span></span></span>
  <div data-index="1" data-key="content1" class="item-content gf_tab-panel gf_tab-panel-active" style="top: -2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);">
    <div data-label="Text Block" data-key="text-block" data-atomgroup="element" id="e-1688134568274" class="element-wrap" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-ver="1" data-id="1688134568274">
      <div class="elm text-edit gf-elm-left gf_gs-text-paragraph-1" data-gemlang="en">
        <p>One-time purchase $54.95</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><span class="gf_tab-accordion-title"><span></span></span>
  <div data-index="2" data-key="content1" class="item-content gf_tab-panel" style="top: -2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);">
    <div data-label="Text Block" data-key="text-block" data-atomgroup="element" id="e-1688134503683" class="element-wrap" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-ver="1" data-id="1688134503683" style="display: block;">
      <div class="elm text-edit gf-elm-left gf_gs-text-paragraph-1" data-gemlang="en">
        <p>Subscribe &amp; save 15% $46.71</p>
        <p>Delivery every 40 Days</p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gf_clearfix"></div>
</div>
```
````

Both the functions or methods mentioned in the description aren't returning true. I am not sure where I'm making mistake

Comment: Your script contains an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: `TRUE` is not defined"

Comment: Also, consider using `for(of)` instead of `.forEach`, because using `.forEach` creates a closure which makes it harder to use statements like `return` inside the loop body (which you are, with `return false`, however `return` inside `.forEach` does not return from the parent `function`, only the closure.

Comment: I don't see Uncaught ReferenceError in my browser console. Can't one set a variable to TRUE or FALSE in JS?

Comment: Click the "Run code snippet" button in your post and you'll see the error. (As for boolean literals: in JS it's case-sensitive: you must use `true` or `false` - not `TRUE` nor `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks, I saw the error by clicking it and changed boolean literals in my code. I'm still unable to get the active class detected. As you know, the HTML contains the class I'm trying to detect with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be so much simpler

You are selecting all the `li` and looking at each but here I just retrieve the active ones

```
const activePurchaseTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-option ul li.gf_tab-active');
```

Use filter instead if you do not want to get the active ones in one go

```
const activeTabVariants = [...purchaseTabs]
  .filter(li => li.matches('.gf_tab-active'))
```

```js
// Declare variable for later use
//Note: selling plan ID differentiates subscription-only product from its regular version
var sellingPlan = 684884014;
var activeClassFound = false;
var activeTabIdentifier;
var gutArmorVariantID = 31638158934062;
var variantData = {
  'id': gutArmorVariantID,
  'quantity': 1,
};

const purchaseTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-option ul li');
// const activePurchaseTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-option ul li.gf_tab-active');
// console.log(activePurchaseTabs.length)

// use filter instead if you do not want to get the active ones in one go
const activeTabVariants = [...purchaseTabs]
  .filter(li => li.matches('.gf_tab-active'))
  .map(li => {
    const index = li.dataset.index;
    return index === 2 ? sellingPlan : `index was ${index}`;
  });
console.log(activeTabVariants)
```

```html
<div class="gf_restabs module style1 gf_module-left purchase-option gf_restabs_accordion_0" data-activetab="1" data-tabbgcolor="#FFFFFF" data-tabcolor="#333333" data-inactivetabbgcolor="#e0e0e0" data-inactivetabcolor="#8d8d8d" data-bordercolor="#cecece"
  data-bordersize="2px" data-height="">
  <ul>
    <li class="gf_tab gf_tab-active" data-index="1" style="margin-left: 0px; border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);"><span class="item-content" data-index="1" data-key="content"><div data-label="Text Block" id="e-1688134412404-2" class="element-wrap" data-tool="0" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-id="1688134412404-2" data-ver="1"><div class="elm text-edit gf_gs-text-paragraph-1">One-time purchase</div></div></span>
      <span class="gf_tab-bottom" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 2px; bottom: -2px;"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="gf_tab" data-index="2" style="margin-left: -2px; border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206); background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224); color: rgb(141, 141, 141);"><span class="item-content" data-index="2" data-key="content"><div data-label="Text Block" id="e-1688134412404-1" class="element-wrap" data-tool="0" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-id="1688134412404-1" data-ver="1"><div class="elm text-edit gf_gs-text-paragraph-1">Subscribe &amp; Save</div></div></span>
      <span class="gf_tab-bottom"></span>
    </li>
  </ul><span class="gf_tab-accordion-title"><span></span></span>
  <div data-index="1" data-key="content1" class="item-content gf_tab-panel gf_tab-panel-active" style="top: -2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);">
    <div data-label="Text Block" data-key="text-block" data-atomgroup="element" id="e-1688134568274" class="element-wrap" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-ver="1" data-id="1688134568274">
      <div class="elm text-edit gf-elm-left gf_gs-text-paragraph-1" data-gemlang="en">
        <p>One-time purchase $54.95</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><span class="gf_tab-accordion-title"><span></span></span>
  <div data-index="2" data-key="content1" class="item-content gf_tab-panel" style="top: -2px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 2px solid rgb(206, 206, 206);">
    <div data-label="Text Block" data-key="text-block" data-atomgroup="element" id="e-1688134503683" class="element-wrap" data-icon="gpicon-textblock" data-ver="1" data-id="1688134503683" style="display: block;">
      <div class="elm text-edit gf-elm-left gf_gs-text-paragraph-1" data-gemlang="en">
        <p>Subscribe &amp; save 15% $46.71</p>
        <p>Delivery every 40 Days</p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gf_clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Grateful for the simplest form of the answer. However, I request you to share an answer with this line `const purchaseTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.purchase-option ul li');` intact. I'm asking this because I'm using `purchaseTabs ` again somewhere below in the script to add event listener to each element.

Comment: Thank you very much. One last question, why is this `const index = li.dataset.index;`? I need the value of attribute `data-index` of active li

Comment: I tried your solution, but it returned empty string instead of `sellingPlan`. I have your code added in this page https://getgutarmor.com/pages/gutarmor-90-ct

Comment: Since I'm testing this on a Shopify development theme, you need to first open this preview theme link https://fgq4gp4xo4wazt4p-1400864814.shopifypreview.com before visiting the page linked in earlier comment to see your code.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not have time right now. It works on the static code you gave us

Comment: Ok, I understand. Great to hear that it works on the HTML I posted. I will make it work on the page. When you find time, kindly visit the page.

Comment: It is working after I put the code within setTimeout() with 300milliseconds. Thank you very much. Finally, this `index was ${index}` is coming as a a plain string without outputting the value for index. Please suggest what to do here

Comment: What is the expected value? I do `const index = li.dataset.index;` so in the html above it is "1". If you want a number do `$(+index}`